# Evaluate div.innerHTML with document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write information from external script to my div. I have a html page with div, and write external script to div with `window.onload`.

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='<script src="http://www.klerk.ru/kurs/informer/informer_txt/?stcbrf=1"></script>';
eval(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
```

In this external script there are several `document.write`'s, but it doesn't work.

My question is how to execute `document.write` into definite `div`?

But, is it possible to do something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <script src="http://www.klerk.ru/kurs/informer/informer_txt/?stcbrf=1"></script>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and will `document.write` in script write data to the `td`?

Comment: You can't `eval` HTML, just JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't load a javascript source file that late, it has to come into the browser during the initial page load, before any javascript runs.  a javascript reference like that cannot be accessed (technical reasons are unknown to me, I'm assuming it's security related).

You can run the eval against a block of javascript code, but not against a javascript file(reference).